# Codigo JQuery a JS puro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas el día de ayer hice una pregunta a la cual me respondieron de manera exitosa, solamente que al momento de implementarla en mi proyecto, trabajo con plantillas personalizadas de Blogger quise agregar el código de JQuery y no me detecta la función.

```
$('.custom-play').click(function(){
$(this).hide();
$('#content_video').get(0).play();});
```

Hay manera de hacer esa porción de código a JavaScript puro?

Comment: ¿Cómo estás intentando agregar la librería de JQuery?

Comment: La estoy agregando de esta manera
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: El orden también es importante, ¿en que lugar la estás añadiendo? Tendría que estar antes de tus ficheros .js personalizados y antes de todas las librerías que dependan de JQuery para funcionar.

Comment: Están antes de empezar agregar el código js

Comment: ¿Y en la consola del navegador te da algún error?

Comment: Que tal Francisco puse la función en la consola y cuando le doy click al botón si desaparece pero no reproduce el vídeo, te anexo lo que me arroja la consola

VM169833:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:31)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: No me refería a ejecutar la función en la consola. Me refería a si al abrir la consola te aparece algún error por defecto. Si te sale algún error es que seguramente no tengas bien puesto el JQuery.

Comment: Entiendo, pero no al momento de abrir la consola no aparece ningún error de la libreria

Comment: Entonces tiene pinta de que no está entrando a la función pero con el código que nos muestras actualmente es imposible reproducir tu error. ¿Estás seguro que hay algún elemento en la página que tiene la clase `.custom-play`? ¿No estará `#content_video` dentro de `.custom-play`? Si ocultas `.custom-play` con la función `hide()` y `#content_video` está dentro no creo que puedas hacer referencia a él.

Comment: Este es el ejemplo que me dieron ayer, es hacer algo parecido a eso.
https://jsfiddle.net/eccu8m24/23/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo ideal sería que resolvieras el problema con `jQuery` pero si quieres la alternativa con `Javascript` puro, aquí la tienes:

```js
var play = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-play");
play[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(this);
  this.style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("video").play();
});
```

```css
.custom-play {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("../images/button-play.png") center center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="freq-content">
  <video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source
      src="http://html5facil.com/demos/videos/big_buck_bunny.webm"
      type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    <source
      src="http://html5facil.com/demos/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
      type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1,mp4a"'>
    </video><br />
  <div class="custom-play"></div>
</div>
```